# Query SQLite or loops over Cursors, What is Which has better performance in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, cursor

Which is faster and most performance recommended? multi query over DataBase, about 8, or two bigger cursor with all data and three loops

Thanks!

Comment: Its Better to use Multi Query instead of loops...

Answer (score 0):

If you query from multi tables, i recommend you to use multi query since it cost much to join tables.